# Row sums with multiple factor conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to sum rows with different conditions, but I got stuck in this part.

This is a similar example of my database:

```
fl<-c("rose", "sunflower", "rose", "sunflower", "lily", "sunflower", "rose", "sunflower")
an<-c("sunbird", "beetle", "beetle", "bee", "bee", "bee", "fly", "bat")
gr<-c("bird", "insect", "insect", "insect", "insect", "insect", "insect", "mammal")
n<-c(2, 3, 7, 15, 23, 48,11, 3)
df<-data.frame(fl, an, gr, n)
```

What I wanted was count the n from the same flower species with the same type of visitor (column gr), even with double entries in a related column (an): as an example, the final product that I'd like to have is a table giving me that sunflowers were visited by 3 different group os animals (bees, beetles and bat), 66 visits from insects (sum of all the animals labels as ''insects'') and 3 from mammals

I don't know if I'm expressing myself properly, but I'd appreciate any kind of help

Comment: Do you need a `rollup` i.e. `library(data.table);setDT(df);rollup(df, j = sum(n), by = c("fl","an","gr"))` or with `cube` `cube(df, j = sum(n), by = c("fl","an","gr"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

fl<-c("rose", "sunflower", "rose", "sunflower", "lily", "sunflower", "rose", "sunflower")
an<-c("sunbird", "beetle", "beetle", "bee", "bee", "bee", "fly", "bat")
gr<-c("bird", "insect", "insect", "insect", "insect", "insect", "insect", "mammal")
n<-c(2, 3, 7, 15, 23, 48,11, 3)
df<-data.frame(fl, an, gr, n, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>%
    group_by(fl, an) %>%
    summarise(howMany = sum(n))
```

Comment: i really appreciated your help, it helped a lot @georgery

Answer (score 0):

I believe @georgery almost had it right..being a fan of tidyverse, I prefer his approach over @arkun.

Here is a slight improvement on his solution:

```
library(dplyr)
fl<-c("rose", "sunflower", "rose", "sunflower", "lily", "sunflower", "rose", "sunflower")
an<-c("sunbird", "beetle", "beetle", "bee", "bee", "bee", "fly", "bat")
gr<-c("bird", "insect", "insect", "insect", "insect", "insect", "insect", "mammal")
n<-c(2, 3, 7, 15, 23, 48,11, 3)
df<-data.frame(fl, an, gr, n, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>% 
  group_by(fl, gr) %>%
  summarise(category = sum(n), typewithincategory=length(unique(an)))
```

The result will be a tibble

```
  fl        gr     category typewithincategory
  <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>              <int>
1 lily      insect       23                  1
2 rose      bird          2                  1
3 rose      insect       18                  2
4 sunflower insect       66                  2
5 sunflower mammal        3                  1
```

Comment: there's just a little thing that your function didn't work well for me: in this example, i have two ''bee'' entries, and the function counted twice. is there a argument that i could use to identify only unique factors in this situation?

Comment: @DaniloCarvalho this is simple. The `length` argument in `summarise` now looks for `unique`. Find updated.